# Sequelize query with dates

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'd like to make a query on dates using SequelizeJS but i don't know how to do and there is nothing on that on the website...

My code :

```
 var day = request.params.day;
 Appointment.findAll({where: ["start.day() = day"]}); // start is my column, format with DATETIME
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your DB there might be some function to extract the day from the column. Never seen the `.day` syntax before though.

```
Appointment.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('day', sequelize.col('start')), day)
});
```

On latest master this should produce something like

```
WHERE DAY("start") = day
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [regular comparison operator](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database), as long as your date is in a valid format. For this purpose you can just create a `Date` object out of the input, and then pass it to the `Sequelize` query, like this:

```
var day = new Date(request.params.day);
Appointment.findAll({where: ['start > ?', day]}).then(function (result) {
    // do stuff here
});
```